# ItemNotMappedException: There is no working folder mapping for XYZ

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I get a Exception throught VersionControlOnNonFatalError-Eventhandler with the following Content:

"There is no working folder mapping for C:\SqlWorkspace."

I have indeed that mapping on my machine. Because of this, i wonder whats wrong.

[image: This is my workspace definition]

The error is provoked on the line "workspace.PendAdd(pc.LocalItem);" where pc.LocalItem contains "C:\SqlWorkspace\Audits.sql"

Workspace.Folders contains: LocalItem: "C:\SqlWorkspace  ServerItem: $/Code/y_Test/SqlHistoryNew  Type: Map}"

Why this error, all settings and parameters seems to be ok?
Other questions like mine gave me no hints, which could have been useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to call "**Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache()**" before any PendAdd / PendDelete / ... call.

The result is: No error and therefore GetPendingChanges() contains your promoted files.

I found the solution on this site: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96a8e35d-1f84-4ac3-8767-e3682dd75e1a/problem-with-pendadd?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Comment: The reason this occurs is that you created the workspace with some client (say VS 2013) that doesn't share its cache with the version of the SDK you're using (say the TFS 2012 SDK) and you need to refresh your local cache from the server.  Refreshing the local workspace cache is a good practice to be in - thanks for this answer!

Comment: In my case, the Client was VS2012 Shell and the SDK with Team Explorer 2012 and the API I use, was TFS2012. So no version conflicts. But good to know, that it is not that unusual to refresh the cache.